# Select change on HTML Click() in IE7,8,9?

Tags: jquery, html, click, mouseenter

I have the following html

```
<div id="active-el">
    <select id="select-drop">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <div>test test test</div>
</div>
```

with said jQuery

```
var active = true;

jQuery('#active-el').live('mouseenter', function () {
    active = true;
    console.log('over active = true');
});

jQuery("html").click(function () {
    if (!active) {
     alert('not selected');   
    }
});
```

You can see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/hLDxM/2/. I have a problem that when I `change` the select dropdown - it becomes not active ?

How can I ensure that even if the user changes the `select` to any value - that the `(html).click` event wont' fire ? That is - regardless of option 1,2,3 or - it's still within the `#active-el` and therefore should be active?

Comment: I don't get an alert on Chrome when changing.

Comment: @pimvdb - try in IE - open JsFiddle and IE console - you'll notice it doesn't work when change select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: used `.change()` in the end to resolve this.

Noted that - `.live(change,function() {});` doesn't work in jQuery 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you are trying to do but try just change

```
    var active = true;

jQuery('#active-el').live('mouseover', function () {
    active = true;
    console.log('over active = true');
}).live('mouseout', function () {
    active = false;
    console.log('over not active = false');
});

jQuery("html").click(function () {
    if (!active) {
     alert('not selected');   
    }
});
```

to mouseout and mouseover instead of mouseenter and mouseleave.

Could you describe what you want to acomplish?

Comment: try in IE via JSFiddle - you'll see the error when you change the select ?